# Kali Linux airodump

Tags: wifi, kali-linux

I think I have a problem with airodump in Kali in Vmware. When I come to the stage that I should enter `airodump - ng wlan0mon`, it does not show me any MAC address it - is just empty between `BSSID` and `channel`, but in my computer it shows a lot more wireless networks available. I have searched about it, but I couldn't find any help.

[image]

Comment: Additionally, I have done airmon-ng start wlan0 and airmon-ng check kill.

Comment: does your wireless hardware supports monitor mode ?

Comment: I am not sure how to know that?

Comment: When running `airmon-ng start` you should get a new wireless interface mon0 or something similar , also try to change/specify the channel , 
for example `airmon-ng start wlan0 11` will put your wireless card in monitor mode on channel 11 ( try with channels 1 , 6 and 11 )

Comment: Do I supposed to plug my lan cable to modem?

Comment: By the way Channel is changing in the picture above itself.

Comment: I have tired to change the channel, but it didn't make anything different.

Comment: Sorry I can't see the picture , my company is filtering sharing websites .. hope someone else can help you solve this , I could look when back home at night , good luck !

Answer (score 2):

Are you using an internal or external wireless USB to monitor network traffic? Either way you'll want to check to make sure the chip set your card uses is supported by airmon-ng (you'll have to do some googling to find out which chip set you're using and if it's supported) and you'll need to change the card from promiscuous to monitor mode. Assuming that airmon-ng does support your network card you'll need to put it in monitor mode. You can do this by entering the following commands in terminal

```
ifconfig *network interface, e.g. wlan0* down
ifconfig *network interface* mode monitor
ifconfig *network interface* up
```

Once you've done that check to make sure there are no processes running on your computer that will interfere with airmon-ng running the following command

```
airmon-ng check *network interface*
```

That should list items like Network Manager, Daemons, Supplicants, etc. You'll need to kill off all of these processes and make sure they don't re-spawn by entering the following commands

```
kill *whatever number is listed before the process, e.g. 1657*
```

Once you've killed all the items that may possibly interfere with airmon-ng, check the status again, if nothing comes up, then start airmon-ng using the following command

```
airmon-ng start *network interface*
```

That should change your network interface from something like wlan0 to wlan0mon. Make sure you're using the new interface when using airmon-ng.

Comment: Thanks for your time to answer my problem. However, I think the problem is vmware. I mean I should use bootable usb or Dual boot for computer. Other than that I should buy some kind of wireless stuff to work in vmware.